# Is it possible to trust self-signed root certificate without match between common name and hostname?

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, android-download-manager, self-signed

The company I work for provides customers with not only client apps, but also the server app. So our customers have their own servers. We can't force them to install certificate issued by trusted CA. Though we have self-signed root certificate, and supply our servers with certificates related to this root.
In android app I want to trust our root certificate so that all certificates related to it become trusted as well.

There is another thing: as Android developer I don't know server address in advance. So certificate's common name won't match hostname. In web browser this mismatch causing warning.

I add root certificate in `network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_company_root_sha256_00f6ac31brt6t2d634"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and registered this config in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
When I try to request server I get:

> - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: EMAILADDRESS=my_company@my_company.com, CN=My_company, OU=My_company,
>   O=My_company, ST=California, C=US
> - Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unacceptable certificate: EMAILADDRESS=my_company@my_company.com, CN=My_company,
>   OU=My_company, O=My_company, ST=California, C=US

Same root certificate imported to Firefox browser makes it work with server with just a warning.

**Is it possible to trust self-signed root certificate without match between common name and hostname?**

NB: I know how to make unsafe okHttpClient which trusts all certificate, so don't offer this option

Comment: You could try a custom `HostnameVerifier` that can confirm that the certificate matches your expectations.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for suggestion. I have never heard about it. I'll try and let you know the result